# What is the smallest possible layout for a simple Python library?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

If sharing a Python library via PyPI, so that someone else can download it with pip and `import` it in their code, the minimal layout that I know of is this:

```
+ foo
  + src
    + bar
      __init__.py
      baz.py
  setup.py
```

I am ignoring the potential presence of `setup.cfg`, `README`, `requirements.txt` and so on. The names `foo` and `bar` are typically the same, sometimes even `baz`, but I'm distinguishing them here for clarity.

It is possible to remove `src` to reduce it further:

```
+ foo
  + bar
    __init__.py
    baz.py
  setup.py
```

Is it possible to achieve an even smaller layout for trivial (but still useful!) libraries? A live example would be ideal, but documentation, a blog post or a working example would be more than adequate. Alternatively, a clear explanation as to why this is **not** achievable is also welcome.

I'm imagining something like...

```
+ foo
  baz.py
  setup.py
```

or the possibly insane...

```
+ foo
  setup.py
```

(although my hunch is that this last is not even achievable)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in the distutils documentation as [Pure Python distribution (by module)](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-module) (thanks @phd for the link.):

> If you’re just distributing a couple of modules, especially if they don’t live in a particular package, you can specify them individually using the py_modules option in the setup script.

With the following example (adapted to match the examples given in the original question):

**Layout**

```
+ foo
  baz.py
  setup.py
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='biff',
      version='1.0',
      py_modules=['baz'],
      )
```

Note that this is legacy documentation [1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html) [2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#distutils-deprecated) but still applicable because the layout remains the same. We can assume the documentation will be moved and updated at some point in the future.